# Runtime Configuration for scheduled AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that is scheduled to run once an hour (as described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-scheduled-events.html).

The function ftps files from a data provider and copies them to S3.

I have a test environment, and a production environment.  For each environment, the ftp address and credentials are different.

How can I configure the lambda function so it can be aware of which environment it's running in, and get the ftp config accordingly?

PS: I am aware of this question: [runtime configuration for AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336261/runtime-configuration-for-aws-lambda-function) , but it did not help me because I am using a scheduled lamdba using the new scheduled lambda functions feature introduced on Oct 8th 2015, and I cannot see a way to get configuration into the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.  For the test version of the function, I am calling it `TEST-CopyFtpFilesToS3` and for the production version of the function I am naming the function `PRODUCTION-CopyFtpFilesToS3`.  This allows me pull out the environment name using a regular expression.

Then I am storing `config/test.json` and `config/production.json` in the zip file that I upload as code for the function.  This zip file will be extracted into the directory `process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` when the function runs.  So I can load that file and get the config I need.

Some people don't like storing the config in the code zip file, which is fine - you can just load a file from S3 or use whatever strategy you like.

Code for reading the file from the zip:

```
const readConfiguration = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let environment = /^(.*?)-.*/.exec(process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME)[1].toLowerCase();
    console.log(`environment is ${environment}`);

    fs.readFile(`${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/config/${environment}.json`, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var config = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(`configuration is ${data}`);
        resolve(config);
      }
    });
  });
};
```